# In custom frame environment, how can I control itemize overlay colors?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I made a custom frame environment with dark background and white foreground. Unfortunately `itemize` overlays stopped working for such combination, only marker for currently highlighted item changes it's appearance.

Is there some variable that controls how overlay alters text in given environment?

I looked around the web and the questions are either how to change behaviour of one item or how to control sequence of actions. I also tried [Beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dramatis personae:

```
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\usebeamercolor[bg]{background canvas}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

I didn't set `\usebeamercolor[bg]` so it was probably still white. When `\setbeamercovered` is set to `transparent` it uses a blend of bg and fg colors, so with white bg it stayed white.
Found in [Beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) 17.6 Transparency effects